# TestCafe - bypass Google telephone verification?

Tags: google-chrome, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When running any TestCafe tests locally (with cache cleared or Incognito), I can always achieve logging into my Google Account that is integrated with my application.

However, I am using CircleCI to run my tests in a CI/CD pipeline. Anytime I execute a tests that requires Google Sign-in, I am always required to perform additional validation (by entering telephone number).

How have other users by-passed this 2fa for their CI/CD pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

Hypothetically, it's possible to send a verification code from the phone to your tests but it will be difficult. I suggest you turn off the second factor for Google Sign-in authorization. It makes sense because you are testing a web-site functionality and not Google Sign-in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The account we are using is a Testing account, but it is within our company's G-Suite account.  Thus the security parameters are control and set.  Disabling a security measure on an account doesn't seem the 'best' alternative.  I can keep digging.